# entity as config for another entity

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, doctrine-orm, constraints

I'm building a Symfony2 site using Doctrine ORM. I have an entity, `Experiment`, some of whose property constraints depend on the value of its `sop` property.  `Experiment::$sop` is another entity, `SOP`, which essentially acts as a config for `Experiment`.

### Questions:

- Is using one entity as the config for another entity a design pattern? If so, which one? And is it a good idea?
- Will this structure work well with Symfony and Doctrine?
- has anyone seen a working example of a similar structure that I could study?

### Experiment entity

```
namespace ACC\ExperimentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ACC\Traits\BlameableTrait;
use ACC\Traits\FileCollectionTrait;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ACC\ExperimentBundle\Validator\Constraints as ACCAssert;

/**
 * Experiment
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ACCAssert\CompliesWithSOP //not yet written
 */
class Experiment {

    use BlameableTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use FileCollectionTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min = "5")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="conclusions", type="text")
     */
    protected $conclusions;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SOP")
    * @JoinColumn(name="sop_id", referecedColumnName="id")
    * @var SOP
    * Experiment class constraint will be based on this
    */
    protected $sop;

    // below properties will have constraints based on $this->sop

    protected $inputsamples;
    protected $outputsamples;
    protected $observations;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->inputsamples = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->outputsamples = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->observations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
    }

  // ...
}
```

### SOP entity

```
namespace ACC\SOPBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ACC\Traits\BlameableTrait;
use ACC\Traits\FileCollectionTrait;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * SOP
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(  name="SOP")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class SOP
{
    use BlameableTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use FileCollectionTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min = "1")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inputsampletype", type="string")
     * used to constrain Experiment::$inputsamples
     */
    protected $inputsampletype;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="outputsampletype", type="string")
     * used to constrain Experiment::$outputsamples
     */
    protected $outputsampletype;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="outputsampletype", type="string") // or maybe this is a collection of types
     * used to constrain Experiment::$observations
     */
    protected $observationtype; // or maybe types

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on solving it this way, you might want to add asserts on your fields that should depend on your sop field, or a custom validator to validate the whole entity outside of the form.

Comment: that's precisely what I intended to do. But, when you say *insist*, are you implying that it's not a good model? If so, what might work better?

Comment: Another way would be to modify the form, so to force constraints on the user input as the form is rendered, not afterwards, so you could disable some fields or whatever depending on the sop value in the entity you build the form for

Answer (score 0):

an *entity* is a business entity. A logical concept of business. Configuration is a property of an entity.

So, I would say the relationship is wrong.

The best way to manage this is to decouple them  and use a join table. Then in your Primary entity you essentially have a map of property->value. After all, the same SOP could apply to any number of experiments

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERIMENTS
(
  PK INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  WHATEVER VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE SOPS
(
  PK INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  VALUE VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EXPERIEMENT_SOPS
(
  EXP_PK INT NOT NULL,
  SOP_PK INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (EXP_PK) REFERENCES Experiements(PK),
  FOREIGN KEY (SOP_PK) REFERENCES SOPS(PK),
  UNIQUE KEY UNQ_SOPS UNIQUE(EXP_PK,SOP_PK)
);
```

Comment: the relationship between `Experiment` and `SOP` is unidirectional. `SOP` doesn't care what experiments it is used on and each `Experiment` can only have one `SOP`.

Comment: Ah. I had assumed That an SOP could be reapplied. I thought it meant Standard Operating Procedure. My assumption about your business rules where wrong but my conclusion about the properties/entities is still right

Comment: Sure, an SOP can be reapplied. It just doesn't need to know about the Experiments that use it. The table structure would have an `sop_id` in the Experiment table. That's all that's necessary.

Comment: The join table also allows you to have many-to-many. Alternatively, you can make the EXP_ID the Primary Key as well and so you have a 1->many but don't bind the SOP to the Experiment entity. I would have to know more about your business world to know which is best

Answer (score 0):

Is inputsample, outputsample, observations going to be Entities as well? Why are they being initialized as `ArrayCollection()`

I feel like I need more information about what you are trying to achieve. But I can say that you might consider creating a service ( e.g. ExperimentManager() ) and this service can do all the validations you require.

If the validation is as simple as comparing the inputsampletype with the inputsample being added. Then you can do that bit in the setters of your experiment entity. Something along these lines:

```
public function addInputSample(InputSample $sample)
{
    $validType = $this->getSOP()->getInputSampleType();

    if($sample->getType() == $validType) {
        $this->inputsamples[] = $sample;
    } else {
        // invalid sample type
    }
}
```

Comment: `$inputsamples` et. al. will be collections of other entities. In the case of `$inputsamples`, a collection of `Sample`s. `$sop` will limit which subclass of `Sample` that the collection can contain. I had intended to do that with a class constraint, as that is how validation is usually accomplished in Symfony.